# Swing cover windows

Tags: java, swing

I am making a login page separate from winlogin which I have as auto-login. The login page is fine to create and using compare from a list I can check username and passwords. I tried making it, and it was fine except I could manipulate the window (close it, resize it, end process etc.)

My question is, How can I make this login GUI the only thing a user can use until a user is authenticated?

Comment: Is this in Java or C#? Either way it would seem the log-in should be done using a modal dialog (not sure if same term used for C# - that is what Java would call it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear if the original poster wants a Java or a C# solution

Comment: The title says "Swing cover windows", so I guess it's supposed to be a Java Swing solution.

Comment: Consider a [modal dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: @copeg I'd give you a +1 for the modal dialog, as this was perfect

Comment: *"The reason I tagged java and C# is both can be used for computer applications, and I briefly know both"* Only tags *relevant to the question* at hand should be added. *"I'd give you a +1 for the modal dialog, as this was perfect"* Did you read all the way to the end of my first comment?!?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to accomplish is to create a JPanel with username JTextField and password JPasswordField and use JOptionPane to show that JPanel in a modal dialog box with the proper ok-cancel options, like:

```
LoginPanel myLoginPanel = ...;
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog("Login", myLoginPanel);

String user = myLoginPanel.getUserId();
String pass = myLoginPanel.getPassword();
login(user,pass);
```

Comment: yea that's what I did, but the problem I asked exists, which is I don't want the user to be able to access the windows behind the panel

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it using a modal dialog: Here we use a `JOptionPane` that has the `ui` panel as the parent. The `ui` panel and the frame it is in are not accessible until the user dismisses the dialog. Unless the user selects the `Yes` option, the main GUI (showing simply `logged in`) remains hidden as one card in a card layout.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BlockTheFrame {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    BlockTheFrame() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        ui = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        JLabel login = new JLabel("Log in");
        login.setFont(login.getFont().deriveFont(200f));
        ui.add(login, "login");

        ui.add(new JLabel("logged in"), "loggedin");
    }

    public void login() {
                JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING, 
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(5,5,5,5), 4, 6);
        loginPanel.add(new JLabel("ID"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        loginPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"), gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_LEADING;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        loginPanel.add(new JTextField("enter ID"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        loginPanel.add(new JPasswordField(10), gbc);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(ui, loginPanel);
        if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // here a real app would check the results of the ID/password
            cardLayout.show(ui, "loggedin");
        } 

    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                BlockTheFrame o = new BlockTheFrame();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
                o.login();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```